# Save method does not save JSON data in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mean

I have a schema as following in Node.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ContactSchema = mongoose.Schema({

first_name:{
  type:String,
  //required:true
},
last_name:{
  type:String,
  //required:true
},
phone:{
  type:String,
  //required:true
}
});

const Contact  = module.exports = mongoose.model('Contact',ContactSchema);
```

Now I am trying to save the object from router.js using Postman:

```
//router.js

 const Contact = require('../models/contacts');

//Create a contact list node server (mongodb)
router.post('/contact',(req,res,next)=>{
  var newContact = new Contact({
  first_name:req.body.first_name,
  last_name:req.body.last_name,
  phone:req.body.phone
  });

  //Save contact list and add call back as well
  newContact.save((err,contact)=>{
  if (err){
      res.json({msg:'Failed to add contact list'});
  } else {
    res.json(contact);
  }

  });
});
```

And passing JSON from Postman as:

```
{

"first_name": "Sunil",
"last_name": "fdgf",
"phone": "8557988004"

}
```

So it save only the id in MongoDB not other field. What's wrong here?

Comment: can you console.log the req.body to check the data

Comment: I did but using postman it does not print any data. console.log(req.body); it does not print anything

Comment: Have you used body-parser in your app?

Comment: yes.var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
//Add middle wear bodyParser
  app.use(bodyParser.json());

Comment: It only save the id.

  "_id": ObjectId("5bd2ba3685095a3119cee80f"),
   "__v": NumberInt(0)

Comment: How are you sending body from postman, form-data or url-incoded... or raw body with json type, Try sending with row body and json data with json type